# How do I remove a closed Gmail account from the Google sign in box

Tags: gmail

Closed one of my emails and I can no longer get into it but it still keeps showing up on the sign in box.  I tried the remove account button but it doesn't show the account there.  Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: Sorry, no that doesn't work.

Comment: could you post here an image how it looks like?  And provide more info on which OS and browser you use.